# Tcl tool similar to Quickcheck or ScalaCheck

Tags: tcl

Is there an automatic test case generated available for Tcl? Similar to quickcheck or scala check? An internet search did not reveal any library.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Indeed, I've not heard of QuickCheck before; is it just doing fuzz testing driven off a little DSL? How on earth could you ever have confidence that what it asserts is meaningful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: Nothing that I'm aware of, but you can code it on top of tcltest easily enough.

---

I looked into some QuickCheck and ScalaCheck tutorials. Interesting, but they have the problem of not guaranteeing to find problems. The examples all nicely show how things can work, when problems are found with *short* inputs, but with the stochastic input models (poisson distributions I suspect?) used I really don't think there's much chance of finding upper-bound or specific-value failures unless you feed through a very large amount of data indeed.

There's also the problem that Tcl code is in general stateful; testing when you've got state about requires a more complex approach. Basically, you *in general* need an extra piece of code to put the system *into* the state you want to test and another to take the system *out* of that state and return it to quiescent. Good test frameworks have this sort of thing down pat, so it's not actually a real problem. Just a complication you need to be aware of.

But we can use the fact that Tcl is pretty much *all* a domain-specific language to make our own little fuzz tester. (The `upvar` and `uplevel` commands are awesomely useful for this sort of thing.)

```
package require tcltest 2

proc fuzzInteger {var from to count test} {
    upvar 1 $var v
    for {set i 0} {$i < $count} {incr i} {
        set v [expr {$from+int(rand()*($to-$from))}]
        uplevel 1 $test
    }
}
proc fuzzList {var P language count test} {
    upvar 1 $var v
    for {set i 0} {$i < $count} {incr i} {
        set v {}
        while {rand() <= $P} {
            lappend v [lindex $language [expr {int(rand() * [llength $language])}]]
        }
        uplevel 1 $test
    }
}

# Demonstrate by throwing random crap into 'lindex'; it should never produce an error
fuzzList abcList 0.5 {a b c} 500 {
    fuzzInteger foobar 0 20 500 {
        tcltest::test lindex-fuzztest-[incr count] "fuzzed: lindex {$abcList} $foobar" -body {
            lindex $abcList $foobar
        } -match glob -result *
    }
}
# Print the final report
tcltest::cleanupTests
```

In this case, there was no need for state setup/cleanup; those would be handled by the `-setup` and `-cleanup` clauses to the `tcltest::test`. Also note that it's an extremely good idea to record what fuzzed values are used in the title of the test *or* by doing substitutions in the body (the second is harder, BTW; my example above shows the first).